# iscsi_trgt module for kernel 4.5

Tags: drivers, kernel, iscsi

Ubuntu 15.10,
Kernel 4.5

I followed this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-building-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel/ and I'm running Kernel 4.5, but I'm missing the iscsi_trgt module.

Do I have the recompile iscsitarget for the (unsupported) kernel?
If so, I tried that and compiling from the 1.4.20 branch gives me this:

```
iscsitarget-1.4.20.2/src/kernel/iscsi.c:978:7: error: ‘SERVICE_ACTION_IN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  case SERVICE_ACTION_IN:
       ^
```

`systemctl status iscsitarget.service`

```
● iscsitarget.service - LSB: Starts and stops the iSCSI software target
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/iscsitarget)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-03-23 11:16:00 CET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2233 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/iscsitarget start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts and stops the iSCSI software target...
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus iscsitarget[2233]: * Starting iSCSI enterprise target service
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus systemd[1]: iscsitarget.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts and stops the iSCSI software target.
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus systemd[1]: iscsitarget.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus systemd[1]: iscsitarget.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus iscsitarget[2233]: modprobe: FATAL: Module iscsi_trgt not found.
Mar 23 11:16:00 zeus iscsitarget[2233]: ...fail!
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to update then upgrade your current version. If that didn't make it, than I imagine that you don't have required headers try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.2.0.34 
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.2.0.34
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Apologies, I really do suck at writing posts, I edited my OP.

Comment: First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.5.0-040500-generic
Building initial module for 4.5.0-040500-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.5.0-040500-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/iscsitarget/1.4.20.3+svn502/build/make.log for more information.
Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...